# Missing iOS Distribution signing identity / "Certificate has an invalid issuer"

Tags: ios, xcode

EDIT:

We have found out that this problem is common to many users starting on February 14th, due to Apple's WWDR Intermediate Certificate expiration.

---

I have had this problem for the last 6 hours and as much as I have researched it, haven't been able to find the answer.

I updated a previously submitted app, and tried to Archive and Upload it to the app store. However, in the organizer I am getting an error: "Missing iOS Distribution signing identity for [my name]." After a lot of research, I tried reseting my Distribution Certificate in different ways, restarting XCode plus an array of different things.

[image: Organizer Error]

The closest I got to an answer is that I noticed that my Distribution Certificate in Keychain says "This certificate has an invalid issuer." But I haven't been able to fix that problem either.

[image: Keychain Error]

Can somebody help?

Comment: Hi Matt, I edited the question to reflect that this is a new problem regarding the WWDR Intermediate Certificate expiration. Other posts that are dated before February 14th, might be misleading to the potential solution. Could you please let me know if this corrects the problem? I need to avoid downvotes :(

Comment: This doesn't help in the case of the iPhone Developer/Distributor certificates being validated.  I removed them, added the appropriate WWDR certs expiring in 2023, re-downloaded my certificates, re-installed them to Keychain Access and they are still marked, "invalid issuer"

Answer (score 11):

[You are not alone](https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/45siza/this_certificate_has_an_invalid_issuer/)

Looks like Apple's WWDR Intermediate Certificate expired

Comment: Is there a way around it to upload an app?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/support/certificates/expiration/

Comment: I tried to do it but still the same issue

Comment: keychain. view > show expired certificates. make sure to delete the expired apple world relation certificate from both Login and System keychains

Comment: Does this mean that I should change the Provision Profile? In this case, the SSKeyChain for my Apps will be updated on all devices..... so bad

Comment: Following this link for step by step details and solution. http://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/2016/02/this-certificate-has-invalid-issuer-in.html